# Form validation using Javascript in Laravel application

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I have a Laravel project. Not done by me. But I'm managing the application now. I have faced a problem in the project. Need to remove some validation. To make a mandatory project optional. Here's the view file.

```
{!! Form::open(array('url' => 'service/tripbuddy', 'method' => 'POST', 'id' => 'frm_trip_package')) !!}
```

This is the blade template for form. And this is the HTML input I need to remove required validation part.

```
<div class="form-group col-md-3 col-sm-12">
    <label>Number of People <span class="required">*</span></label>
    <input class="form-control" name="no_of_people" id="no_of_people" type="number"
           value="{{isset($cur_package) ? $cur_package->no_of_people : null}}">
</div>
```

And also I found this javascript code also related to the validation process. But I changed that. Nothing happened.

```
var validator = new FormValidator('frm_trip_package', [{
name: 'title',
display: 'Title',
rules: 'required|max_length[50]'
},{
    name: 'description',
    display: 'Description',
    rules: 'required|max_length[2500]|min_length[90]'
}, {
    name: 'no_of_people',
    display: 'Number of people',
    rules: 'required'
}, {
    name: 'iteneries',
    display: 'Itineraries',
    rules: 'required'
}, {
    name: 'method_of_travel',
    display: 'Method of travel',
    rules: 'required'
}, {
    name: 'total_hours',
    display: 'Total Hours',
    rules: 'required'
}, {
    name: 'total_minutes',
    display: 'Total Minutes',
    rules: 'required'
}, {
    name: 'price',
    display: 'Price',
    rules: 'required|max_length[8]'
}, {
    name: 'terms',
    display: 'Terms',
    rules: 'required'
}, {
    name: 'images',
    display: 'Images',
    rules: 'required'
}, {
    name: 'pricing_type',
    display: 'Pricing Type',
    rules: 'required'
}
], function (errors, event) {
if (errors.length > 0) {
    var errorString = '<a href="#" class="close" onclick="hideTripErrorMessages()">&times;</a>';

    for (var i = 0, errorLength = errors.length; i < errorLength; i++) {
        if (errors[i].name == 'images') {
            errors[i].message = 'Please add images to your package';
        }
        errorString += errors[i].message + '<br />';
    }

    $("#trip_error_box").show();
    $("#trip_error_box").html(errorString);
}
});
```

Is this a standard way of validating ? Can someone please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Update this

```
{
    name: 'description',
    display: 'Description',
    rules: 'required|max_length[2500]|min_length[90]'
}
```

with this and try

```
{
        name: 'description',
        display: 'Description',
        rules: 'max_length[2500]|min_length[90]'
    }
```

Comment: Do or do not. There is no "try". A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 0):

Change the javascript code to

```
var validator = new FormValidator('frm_trip_package', [{
    name: 'title',
    display: 'Title',
    rules: 'required|max_length[50]'
},{
    name: 'description',
    display: 'Description',
    rules: 'required|max_length[2500]|min_length[90]'
}, {
    name: 'iteneries',
    display: 'Itineraries',
    rules: 'required'
}, {
    name: 'method_of_travel',
    display: 'Method of travel',
    rules: 'required'
}, {
    name: 'total_hours',
    display: 'Total Hours',
    rules: 'required'
}, {
    name: 'total_minutes',
    display: 'Total Minutes',
    rules: 'required'
}, {
    name: 'price',
    display: 'Price',
    rules: 'required|max_length[8]'
}, {
    name: 'terms',
    display: 'Terms',
    rules: 'required'
}, {
    name: 'images',
    display: 'Images',
    rules: 'required'
}, {
    name: 'pricing_type',
    display: 'Pricing Type',
    rules: 'required'
}
], function (errors, event) {
    if (errors.length > 0) {
        var errorString = '<a href="#" class="close" onclick="hideTripErrorMessages()">&times;</a>';

        for (var i = 0, errorLength = errors.length; i < errorLength; i++) {
            if (errors[i].name == 'images') {
                errors[i].message = 'Please add images to your package';
            }
            errorString += errors[i].message + '<br />';
        }

        $("#trip_error_box").show();
        $("#trip_error_box").html(errorString);
    }
});
```

Update label to

```
<label>Number of People</label>
```

This is very simple, all you had to do was search for the form input id in the validator rules and remove it.

Comment: Hey bro. thanks. I removed that. Earlier before I remove, i couldn't press submit. Now I can. But the problem is page is reloading and again the error is there. Number of people is required.

Comment: I'm new to Laravel, can you tell me how the form submission step goes.